# Reporting Services 2010 RDLC: Passing Querystring Parameters from an RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, webforms, rdlc, report-designer

I'm trying to build a simple RDLC report that shows some data, and has a 'select' link that sends the browser off to a certain url with some data in the querystring (a key).

In the vs2010 report designer, I can double-click on the column, then select action, and there are a bunch of thigns that seem like they might work. But none of them do.

Under 'enable as a hyperlink' I can pick 'go to url' but there aren't any parameter options to pass.

I also tried 'go to report' on the off chance that I could trick it into doing what I want. Here there *are* parameter options, but it knows that my url is not a report and the "select" link renders as text (not clickable).

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure this used to work in vs2008, and it seems like something that *must* be doable. But I've been pulling out my hair for several hours on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the expression builder?  <strike>I am writing a blog post on this.</strike>

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/12/adding-a-hyperlink-in-a-client-report-definition-file-rdlc.aspx

Above link not working:
[try this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/Contents/Item/Display/87)

Comment: Raj... Buddy... I wish I could give you ten votes. Thank you very much.

Comment: I do have one question re: your article... What if I want the url to change in production? If I hardcode /localhost/ that won't work. Do I have to pass that in as a parameter, or else put it in the dataset?

Comment: Yes, set the ReportViewer ReportPath. The paths are stored in an xml file or in a SQL table. We use the latter.